# Facebook fbq track for link leaving domain

Tags: facebook

I need to track clicks in Facebook to a link that leave my domain. It appears that FB recommends this code...

```
<div id="getAuthorized"><a target="_blank" href="https://anothersite.com">GET AUTHORIZED</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('getAuthorized');
  button.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
      fbq('trackCustom', 'GetAuthorized', {
        content_name: 'Get Authorized Button'
      });          
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

My question is whether the new page will load before the script fires, causing the event to not get recorded.

I know Google supports outbound events, but I can't find anything definitive for Facebook.

Comment: If FB recommends that why wouldn't it work? And if you are not sure if it works why not test it?

Comment: I tested it. FB notice in console suggests changing 'track' to 'trackCustom' so made the change and testing again.